# How to distribute rectangles evenly

Tags: libreoffice

I have 3 rectangles that I want to distribute horizontally evenly.

[image: screenshot]

[According to this](https://help.libreoffice.org/Draw/Arranging,_Aligning_and_Distributing_Objects), there is a Modify > Distribution but I don't see it.

Using LibreOffice 6.0.7.3 in Ubuntu 18.0.4

Comment: This is off-topic for U&L but if you read the page you reference carefully then you will see that the distribution option for objects is in `Draw` and not `Writer`

Comment: Ok thanks. I was wondering if this was the correct forum. I did see a libreoffice tag so I went with it. What would be the correct StackExchange forum for questions such as this?

Comment: No disrespect, but this is not a programming question and posting it in StackOverflow would bring hell from down on high from the neckbeards.

Comment: @bu5hman stackoverflow is absolutely not the right site for this question.  It's a site for asking programming questions.  The tag you've linked appears for questions relating to programming libreoffice macros.  This question might belong on superuser.com.